# \guilsinglright and \quotesinglbase unavailable in encoding OT4 when using package "polski"

Tags: input-encodings, font-encodings, polish

I reinstalled my system completely (changed from Win7 to Win10) and installed MiKTeX 2.9 and TeXnicCenter. Files that used to work with this setup do not anymore. Tried the very basic example for Polish language

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
ęółąśłżźćń
\end{document}
```

and I keep getting an error of commands `\guilsinglright` and `\quotesinglbase` not being available in encoding OT4, no output pdf file is produced. Anybody knows what could be the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: Use `utf8` input encoding (most modern editors encode this way by default nowadays).

Comment: Most likely your document is UTF-8 encoded and not in cp1250. On the other hand, you should also add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, because `OT4` is an outdated kludge.

Comment: Adding fontenc and changing to UTF-8 helped, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error happens at `ł`, which is, in UTF-8, `0xC582`; the second byte (decimal 130), is governed in `cp1250` by

```
\DeclareInputText{130}{\quotesinglbase}
```

(the first byte is decimal 197, which is translated into `\'L`). So the best conjecture is that your file is UTF-8 encoded rather than in the legacy CP1250 encoding.

Solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polski}

\begin{document}

ęółąśłżźćń

\end{document}
```

The OT4 encoding is an outdated kludge that has long been superseded by T1, which supports the entire (modern) Polish alphabet, with the big advantage that hyphenation will consider all characters (with OT4 it doesn't).

[image]